# RadarChart' object has no attribute 'plot

Tags: python

```
def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    (x1, x2) = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    return [(d - y1) / (y2 - y1) * (x2 - x1) + x1 for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data, ranges)]
    
class RadarChart():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges, n_ordinate_levels = 6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8],polar = True, 
        label = "axes{}".format(i)) for i in range(len(variables))]
        _, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, labels = variables)
        
        for txt, angle in zip(text, angles):
            txt.set_rotation(angle - 90)
        
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
        
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i],num = n_ordinate_levels)
            grid_label = [""]+["{:.1f}".format(x) for x in grid[1:]]
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels = grid_label, angle = angles[i])
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
def plot(self, data, args, kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

def fill(self, data, args, kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

def legend(self, args, kw):
        self.ax.legend(args, kw)  
        attributes = ['員工滿意度','雇主評分','工作項目',
              '每月工作時數','工作年資']  

attributes = ['員工滿意度','雇主評分','工作項目',
              '每月工作時數','工作年資'] 

data_stay_mean = data_stay[attributes].mean().values.reshape(1,-1)
data_left_mean = data_left[attributes].mean().values.reshape(1,-1)

datas = np.concatenate((data_stay_mean,data_left_mean),axis = 0)

ranges = [[1e-2, dataset[attr].max()] for attr in attributes]
colors = ["green","red"]
left_types = ["Stayed","Left"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
radar = RadarChart(fig, attributes, ranges)

for data, color, left_type in zip(datas, colors, left_types):
    radar.plot(data, color = color, label = left_type, linewidth=2.0)
    radar.fill(data, alpha = 0.2, color = color)
    radar.legend(loc = 1, fontsize = 'medium')

plt.title('score')
plt.show();
```

I want to draw a radar chart,this is my code,when running the code I get an attributeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-434-bd12605f0a14> in <module>()
     58 
     59 for data, color, left_type in zip(datas, colors, left_types):
---> 60     radar.plot(data, color = color, label = left_type, linewidth=2.0)
     61     radar.fill(data, alpha = 0.2, color = color)
     62     radar.legend(loc = 1, fontsize = 'medium')

AttributeError: 'RadarChart' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

I tried modifying the class RadarChart but nothing works, I still get the same AttributeError, The final output is a blank radar chart, is there anything else I can modify?
(Please ignore the Chinese text, they are working normally).

Comment: If you want `plot` to belong to `class RadarChart()`, shouldn't `def plot` have the same indentation as `def __init__`?

Comment: Indentation is not proper

Comment: This problem has been solved, but I get new problem:
59
60 for data, color, left_type in zip(datas, colors, left_types):
---> 61 radar.plot(data, color = color, label = left_type, linewidth=2.0)
62 radar.fill(data, alpha = 0.2, color = color)
63 radar.legend(loc = 1, figsize = 'medium')

TypeError: plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
'''
I'm about to give up